# Classic ipod 120gb hardrive crash

Tags: itunes, hard-drive, ipod

When I turn my ipod on I get the red circle with an X in it that tells me to contact apple support. I accessed the diagnostics and when I try to run either of the hard drive test the display says (can't open device) ERROR! Diag halt. I'm pretty sure my hard drive is toast and I know how to replace the hard drive but,how do I download software? when I connect it to Itunes on my computer will the software download while it synchronizes? or do I have to download software from apple?

Answer (score 1):

If you can replace the hard drive from your iPod classic with another hard drive from another iPod classic 120GB, then you should be fine. The OS will automatically be on there. If not, it'll download automatically through iTunes. The same case happens if the replacement hard drive has an older version of the firmware.